# PYMySQL Arora Database Insertion Issue(1265, "Data truncated "Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' ,"Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'colname))

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, pymysql

I have an Excel file from that excel file i am inserting the data to MYSQL Arora database. I am able to connect to database. The only issue is while inserting the data into database i am getting below error and my inserting is not happening properly.

How to solve below error?

```
C:\App_New\app\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'daily_upper' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'daily_lower' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'curr_week_date' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'curr_week_price' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'prev_week_date' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'prev_week_price' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'wow_change' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'weekly_upper' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'weekly_lower' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'wow_flag' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'curr_month_date' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'curr_month_price' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'prev_month_date' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'prev_month_price' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'mom_change' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'monthly_upper' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'monthly_lower' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'mom_flag' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'dod_change' at row 1")
  result = self._query(query)
EO_alert_data
object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\App_new\app\eo_processing\eo_alerts_situation\Approach 2\Situation_Model.py", line 781, in main
    qa_instance.insert_daily_exchange_data_daily(daily_exchange_values,SPEND_DATA_JSON,DAILY_EXCHANGE_RATE_TABLE_NAME)
  File "C:\App_new\app\eo_processing\eo_alerts_situation\Approach 2\Insert_alert_data_QA.py", line 350, in insert_daily_exchange_data_daily
    raise e
  File "C:\App_new\app\eo_processing\eo_alerts_situation\Approach 2\Insert_alert_data_QA.py", line 345, in insert_daily_exchange_data_daily
    self.update_bu_ou_situation_QA()
  File "C:\App_new\app\eo_processing\eo_alerts_situation\Approach 2\Insert_alert_data_QA.py", line 358, in update_bu_ou_situation_QA
    if len(df_output)>0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1034, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 880, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 619, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 380, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "C:\App_new\app\eo_processing\eo_alerts_situation\Approach 2\Situation_Model.py", line 825, in <module>
    data_for_alert = main(comm_data,eo_cat_comm,hist_data,lifetime_data,Daily_Thresholds,Weekly_Thresholds,Monthly_Thresholds)
  File "C:\App_new\app\eo_processing\eo_alerts_situation\Approach 2\Situation_Model.py", line 786, in main
    logger.error('Error pushing data in QA :', e)
Message: 'Error pushing data in QA :'
Arguments: (TypeError("object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"),)
```

Comment: Where is your code? Where do you assign a value to `df_output`?

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers below to help you identify the error :

**1.** Most of the the insertion error are actually warnings that says it truncates data if the incoming data length is more than than the length set of the column. For e.g. target column length is char(4) but one of the source values is length 6 i.e. "ABCXYZ"

**2.** TL;DR - source value is string and target column is decimal/integer.
Your question heading hints that there are NULL values which instead is coming as a
string 'NULL' (with quotes) but the target columns are integers and decimal.